# (PyUSB) python code/file not run properly for Open and read txt file from USB (code issue)

Tags: usb, python

(PyUSB) python code/file **not run properly for Open and read txt file from USB (code issue)**

python code only listing the file from "run file" same directory, I want to read txt file USB

- I'm using Linux. I know my USB name is:

  ```
  Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8564:1000 Transcend Information, Inc. JetFlash
  ```
- and the idVendor and idProduct is:

  ```
  idVendor           0x8564 Transcend Information, Inc.   
  idProduct          0x1000 JetFlash
  ```

the run file code is:

```
import usb.core
import usb.util
import os

dev = usb.core.find(idVendor= 0x8564, idProduct=0x1000)

ep = dev[0].interfaces()[0].endpoints()[0]
i=dev[0].interfaces()[0].bInterfaceNumber
dev.reset()

if dev.is_kernel_driver_active(i):
    print("hello")
    
current_directory = os.getcwd()
print(current_directory)  # => /home/borislav/Desktop/bobbyhadz_python

contents = os.listdir(current_directory)
print(contents)  # ️ ['main.py', 'example.py', ...]

# ️ check if the file is in the current directory
print('example-file.txt' in contents)
```

- the output : (only listing the file from "run file" same
  directory, I want to read txt file USB )

  ```
  (base) joy@joy-System-Product-Name:/$ sudo python '/home/joy/fe_dir/The_one_I_want.py'

  /

  ['snap', 'run', 'root', 'sys', 'media', 'lost+found', 'etc', 'boot', 'cdrom', 'lib32', 'usr', 'sbin', 'dev', 'mnt', 'swapfile', 'tmp', 'lib64', 'lib', 'var', 'proc', 'home', 'opt', 'srv', 'bin', 'libx32']

  False (base)

  joy@joy-System-Product-Name:/$
  ```

Comment: Your question title is very confusing. What version of Ubuntu are you using.

Comment: I'm using `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS` ; I checked by `lsb_release -a`

Comment: Please don't put SOLVED in the question title in this question answer site. Click on the gray check mark next to your answer and turn it green to indicate the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

the main idea is to using  `np.loadtxt`  and knowing the txt file path

> data_inside_content2222222 = np.loadtxt("/media/joy/Data/1111.txt",
> dtype='str' , delimiter=",") print(data_inside_content2222222)

the USB txt file's path:

> /media/joy/Data/1111.txt"

- **solved code**

```js
import usb.core
import usb.util
import os
import numpy as np

dev = usb.core.find(idVendor= 0x8564, idProduct=0x1000)

ep = dev[0].interfaces()[0].endpoints()[0]
i=dev[0].interfaces()[0].bInterfaceNumber
dev.reset()

if dev.is_kernel_driver_active(i):
    print("hello joy")
    
    


data_inside_content2222222 = np.loadtxt("/media/joy/Data/1111.txt", dtype='str' , delimiter=",")
print(data_inside_content2222222)
print("= = = = = = = = = = ")


current_directory = os.getcwd()

# ️ /home/borislav/Desktop/bobbyhadz_python
# print(current_directory)


content2222222 = os.listdir("/media/joy/Data")

contents = os.listdir(current_directory)
#print(contents)  # ️ ['main.py', 'example.py', ...]
print("the file in the same directory is: ")
print(content2222222) 

# ️ check if file in current directory
print('example-file.txt' in contents)
```

output:

> (base) joy@joy-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo python
> '/home/joy/fe_dir/10_3try_001.py'
> hello joy
>
> success cool may
> man99999999999999999999999999999999中文

> = = = = = = = = = =

> the file in the same directory is:
>
> ['1111.txt', '2222.txt', '3333.txt', 'System Volume Information']
> False